# Need a suggestion in UI design

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface

i need give the two options to users when they come to my site(like the following) even before loding the main pages of the site.

1. Daily deals
2. discount and Coupon codes

based on the user selection, i need to display the respective pages.

Now my query is "how to give these two option to users for their selection?"... Please suggest how this can be handled... is this same kind of thing is implemented in any of the website to have a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common design, many car dealerships show that as well.  As soon as you visit the landing page, it has a pretty picture, and two BIG buttons: New Cars and Old Cars.  Depending upon which button you click, you go to the two main pages.

So your website can have something like:

- gourav/splash_page  with two big buttons
- gourav/daily_deals
- gourav/couponsetc

One trick to use is that when you find a cookie from one of the two main pages, you can automatically load that page.  But this means that user should be able to switch between the two main sites using a top level menu.

Answer (score 2):

> i need give the two options to users
>   when they come to my site(like the
>   following) *even before loading the
>   main pages of the site*

Are you looking for a message-box styled window(similar to feedback message-box on some websites) or a pop-up window?

Another Option
You can create a page which is displayed to the user when the user visits the site.

From there you can then link to the main page of the website or load the page the user selects from the options.

Answer (score 2):

Don't make them choose. Decide on a default (based on which one is most often what users want) then make it easy to switch. This way, instead of annoying all the users all the time you only slightly annoy some of the users some of the time.

Also, make both pages bookmarkable (eg: example.com/deals and example.com/codes). This way the user can bookmark the variation they want.